# Changed Android Project name now not working at all

Tags: android

I've just changed my Android project name via

> -res -> values -> strings.xml (changed app name)
>
> -Right clicked on project -> refactored -> renamed

Now nothing is working, error codes on every line. This is my final year project and I think I have ruined it.
Any ideas on how to get it working again? 
Ive tried the above 2 steps again but renaming it back to what it was before with no success.

Please help

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? What errors do you see?

Comment: If I try to run it, an error comes up:

Launching InterviewMe! has encountered a problem.
Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.adt (2).

Comment: Did you try to clean the project first then rebuild it?

Comment: Also if I try to change the name back to the original via res> strings.xml or in the manifest it won't even load the xml/manifest code, this error comes up:

Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.

Comment: Thanks! Working now! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that problem too, don't worry there are 2 ways to get that working again.
The first way is that you select Build -> Clean Project and then Build -> Rebuild 
(I would at first try it with the original name, then with the new one)
The other solution, is that you create a new Project and copy-paste your code you already head into that one. That one won't solve your problem with the errors but you got a working version without errors again then

Comment: Thank you, the 1st worked with the new name, you absolute hero!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is going to sound crazy but I went to Help>Install New Software. I clicked the link to see software already installed. I then tried to Uninstall Android Developer Tools. It prompted me to restart and on the restart everything worked! And it didn't even uninstall anything. Weird...